Something not working as expected using prometheus and grafana histograms
Alright, so there must be something i am completely misunderstanding here.
So i have this very simple website. It takes an audio and runs it through a series of processes (noise removal, chunking by silences, transcription, etc).
So i setup prometheus and grafana to monitor these processes and there's a specific metric not working as expected:
transcription_pipeline_latency - Histogram - Labels: from_state; to_state; pipe_id - Records how long it took to go from one process to another
I am attempting to display this data on a heatmap.
here's an excerpt example data:
transcription_pipeline_latency_seconds_bucket{from_status="Created", instance="127.0.0.1:8003", job="django", le="15.0", pipe_id="78", to_status="In Processing Q"} 1

transcription_pipeline_latency_seconds_bucket{from_status="Created", instance="127.0.0.1:8003", job="django", le="25.0", pipe_id="78", to_status="In Processing Q"} 0

This means that for "pipe_id=78" it took between 15 and 25 seconds to go from "created", to "in the processing queue" status. This is what i expect it to look like.
The problem is, the heatmap keeps showing old data. let's say i processed a file 1 hour ago, currently it is still updating the heatmap with the latencies from that file. I expect it to create only one entry per transition.
See this screenshot for reference:
heatmap
So on the above image, there are no files processing during this timeframe. i would expect the graph to be empty.
i've tried multiple different queries, currently i am using:
histogram_quantile(0.99, sum by(le, from_status) (transcription_pipeline_latency_seconds_bucket))

*_bucket behaves as counter. If you want only recent changes consider wrapping your query with something like increase
